# Access Menu Item to Disable/Enable

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsmenuitem

I would like to implement `NSMenuItem`to trigger certain functionality (e.g. "Run Calculation"). How do I access the menu items in order to enable/disable the items based on the app logic? E.g. the "cut" function for text is only enable as menu item when test is selected. "Run Calculation" should only get enabled when certain criteria are given.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `NSMenuItem` conforms to `NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem` which works with the `NSUserInterfaceValidations` protocol. Implement `func validateUserInterfaceItem(_ item: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool`. See [User Interface Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000040i).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably have some view controller or window controller that implements `runCalculation`, like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func runCalculation(_ sender: Any?) {
        print(1 + 1)
    }

}
```

And you have connected the “Run Calculation” menu item's action to the `runCalculation` method of the controller.

To enable and disable the menu item, follow these steps:

1. Make sure the “Calculator” menu itself (of type `NSMenu`) has the “Auto Enables Items” property turned on in IB, or has `autoenablesItems` set to true in code.

   [image: menu auto enables items checkbox]
2. Make your controller conform to the `NSUserInterfaceValidations` protocol:

   ```
   extension ViewController: NSUserInterfaceValidations {
       func validateUserInterfaceItem(_ item: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool {
           // See step 3...
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `validateUserInterfaceItem`, check whether the item's `action` is `runCalculation(_:)`. If so, return true if and only if you want to allow the user to run the calculation:

   ```
   extension ViewController: NSUserInterfaceValidations {
       func validateUserInterfaceItem(_ item: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool {
           switch item.action {

           case #selector(runCalculation(_:))?:
               // Put your real test here.
               return !textField.stringValue.isEmpty

           default: return true
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Its the first time I deal with NSMenu. You helped me a lot!